# How can I resolve error building wheels when trying to install dbt-snowflake?

Tags: python, dbt

I'm trying to install dbt-snowflake on via the command line on my windows 10 machine.  Getting the following error and not sure how to proceed.  Would appreciate any help I can get...

Edit: I should add that I've already downloading the C++ Build Tools but this did not resolve the error.

```
 building 'snowflake.connector.arrow_iterator' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for snowflake-connector-python
Failed to build snowflake-connector-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for snowflake-connector-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Python 3.7 is required.  I downgraded to 3.7 and was able to run install dbt-snowflake without issue.